# randomly select value from a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, html

How do I select random value (property and its key) from the object and append each one to specific div?

```
    <div id="propertydiv"></div>
    <div id="valuediv"></div>

var student = {
                    name : "John Doe",
                    age : "28",
                    gender : "Male"
                };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put the object's keys in an array then you can easily select one at random, maybe a little something like this:

```js
var student = { name : "John Doe", age : "28", gender : "Male" };

var keys = Object.keys(student);
var randomKey = keys[Math.floor(Math.random()*keys.length)];
var randomValue = student[randomKey];

document.getElementById("propertydiv").innerHTML = randomKey;
document.getElementById("valuediv").innerHTML = randomValue;
```

```html
<div id="propertydiv"></div>
<div id="valuediv"></div>
```

(Run the snippet above several times to see the random behaviour.)

Further reading:

- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)
- [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)

Answer (score 3):

You may use it for array of object like...

```
<div id="propertydiv"></div>
<div id="valuediv"></div>

<script>
var student = [
                { name : "John Doe", age : "28", gender : "Male" },
                { name : "Nazmul", age : "22", gender : "Male"},
                { name : "Nadir", age : "6", gender : "Male"}
              ];

var randomObject = Math.floor(Math.random()*student.length);
var keys = Object.keys(student[randomObject]);
var randomKey = keys[Math.floor(Math.random()*keys.length)];
var randomValue = student[randomObject][randomKey];

document.getElementById("propertydiv").innerHTML = randomKey;
document.getElementById("valuediv").innerHTML = randomValue;

</script>
```